# How can I change the text in a <span></span> element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a span element as follows: `<span id="download">Download</span>`. This element is controlled by a few radio buttons. Basically, what I want to do is have 1 button to download the item selected by the radio buttons, but am looking to make it a little more "flashy" by changing the text inside the `<span>` to say more specifically what they are downloading. The span is the downloading button, and I have it animated so that the span calls slideUp(), then should change the text, then return by slideDown().Here is the code I am using that does not want to work.

```
$("input[name=method]").change(function() {
    if($("input[name=method]").val() == 'installer') {
        $('#download').slideUp(500);
        $('#download').removeClass("downloadRequest").removeClass("styling").css({"cursor":"default"});
        $('#download').text("Download");
        $('#download').addClass("downloadRequest").addClass("styling").css({"cursor":"pointer"});
        $('#download').slideDown(500);
    }
    else if($("input[name=method]").val() == 'url') {
        $('#download').slideUp(500);
        $('#download').removeClass("downloadRequest").removeClass("styling").css({"cursor":"default"});
        $('#download').text("Download From Vendor Website");
        $('#download').addClass("styling").addClass("downloadRequest").css({"cursor":"pointer"});
        $('#download').slideDown(500);
    }
});
```

I changed the code a bit to be more readable so I know that it doesn't have the short code that jQuery so eloquently allows. Everything in the code works, with the exception of the changing of the text inside the span. I'm sure its a simple solution that I am just overlooking.

Any help is appreciated,

Eric R.

Comment: `$('#download').text("Download");` is correct for changing the text inside of the `<span>`. There must be some other issue causing it not to work.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another element with the same ID? Your code looks fine (aside from lack of variables).

Comment: On a side note, your code is very inefficient.  Repeatedly calling `$('#download')` will invoke the selectors parser followed by `querySelector` or `getElementById`, meaning you're traversing the DOM multiple times.  You should store `$('#download')` in a variable or chain all the methods and only look for it once.

Comment: "I changed the code a bit to be more readable"...**don't do this**.  If you're not posting the problem, then we may not see the problem, make sure you're posting the code you're running, otherwise any number of conversion errors or fixes may be introduced.  Have you tried the literal code in your question?

Comment: I know, I made it inefficient purely to make it easier for everyone to read. That is not how my code looks--everything is chained.

@Nick I just added the selectors in between all the methods. Doesn't change the output, just the way it reads. (and makes it very inefficient)

Comment: @Eric - You can slim that all down to 1 set of code with a conditional statement inside the `.text()`...my point was to never modify the code, only remove the irrelevant bits, most people here are used to viewing the optimized version, best to leave it whenever possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this isn't working is that `$("input[name=method]")` matches every element that is of type input and has an attribute of name with the value of "method". That is, if you are using check boxes each and every checkbox <del>you have</del> with that name. I believe the `val` method returns the value of the first match element - regardless of whether it is checked or not.

See this test page: http://jsbin.com/igixa4

You might want to add [the `:checked` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).

So how I would implement it:

```
$("input[name=method]").change(function() {
  $download = $('#download');
  $download.slideUp(500).removeClass("downloadRequest").removeClass("styling")
    .css({"cursor":"default"});
  switch($("input[name=method]:checked").val()) {
    case 'installer' :
      $download.text("Download");
      break;
    case 'url':
      $download.text("Download From Vendor Website");
      break;
  }
  $download.addClass("styling").addClass("downloadRequest")
    .css({"cursor":"pointer"}).slideDown(500);       
});
```

Comment: Why would every checkbox have `method` set to the `name` attribute?  Regardless of whether or not it's right, your answer is extremely assumptive.

Comment: Thanks. I completely overlooked the selectors details in the API. It does in fact return the value of the first one every time. I changed it to $("input:radio[name=method]:checked"].val() and that returns it properly.

Comment: @Andy I guess I wrote it ina bit of a confusing manner. I tried to clarify a bit.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
$('#download').html("Download From Vendor Website")
```

or

```
$('#download').val("Download From Vendor Website")
```

Comment: If `text` is not working, what makes you think this would work?

Comment: Not a good idea to use `.html()` when you are just trying to change text.

Comment: it's worth a try, and if there is a duplicate id issue, maybe it will render another part of the page incorrectly and help identify it.

Comment: `.val()` will also blow up in IE since its not an `<input>` element its just a `<span>`

Comment: if everything else in the code is working, then it probably isn't a duplicate id issue either.

Comment: Well using `.html()` and `.val()` isn't making anything better.

Comment: I understand your point, and I agree that using .text is the preferred method.  But for debugging purposes, it may be worth trying changes like this at times, providing they aren't too time consuming or too much of an alteration to the code.